# How to resolve only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm attempting to train a model and am getting an error on the following code when I'm trying to train the model. Below is the full line of code; however, I've narrowed it down to the clf and I believe more specifically the problem lies within the .fit portion of the code,

```
# Train a SelfPacedEnsembleClassifier
clf = SelfPacedEnsembleClassifier(
    n_estimators=5,
    random_state=42,
).fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict & Evaluate
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
score = average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
print ("SelfPacedEnsemble {} | AUPRC: {:.3f} | #Training Samples: {:d}".format(
    len(clf.estimators_), score, sum(clf.estimators_n_training_samples_)
    ))
```

My understanding of the problem is that it can't index an array with a float, but I'm not seeing where that is being done. What am I missing?

Below is the full error. Thank you.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-9c19852e871f> in <module>
      1 # Train a SelfPacedEnsembleClassifier
----> 2 clf = SelfPacedEnsembleClassifier(
      3     n_estimators=5,
      4     random_state=42,
      5 ).fit(X_train, y_train)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\self_paced_ensemble\self_paced_ensemble\_self_paced_ensemble.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    321         self : object
    322         """
--> 323         return super().fit(
    324             X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs
    325         )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\self_paced_ensemble\utils\_validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    562             )
    563         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
--> 564         return f(**kwargs)
    565 
    566     return inner_f
```

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: That's not the full traceback, is it?  Also we don't know anything about this `self_paced_ensemble` package, or the arguments you give it.  Indexing with strings can also produce this error.

Comment: FIgured it out. I had a line of code changing my predictor variable to a INT. However, the cell before it (a graph) had a error, but that cell didn't run. Once I ran that cell, it worked.